# How to extend from a generic TypeScript type?

Tags: typescript, generics, inheritance

I want to have a type/interface that includes all properties from a given generic type and adds some more, i. e., that **extends** it. Also, I want to be able to "downcast" any object of this type to the one it extends.

I will never instantiate any new object of the type that adds the property, since it will only act as a "contract" for an object. Thus, I presume it should never be a class.

So far I've tried to intersect both types, like so:

```
class MyClass{
   prop1: string;
   prop2: string;

   constructor(){
      this.prop1 = '1';
      this.prop2 = '2';
   }
}

type MyType<T> = T & {
   additionalProp: string;
}

myService.getData()
   .subscribe((res: MyType<MyClass>) => {
      //Do something with res.additionalProp...

      //This one should *not* have "additionalProp" yet it somehow does.
      let anObject: MyClass = <MyClass>res;

      console.log(anObject);
      //output: {prop1: '1', prop2: '2', additionalProp: 'valuefromresponse'}
   });
```

It may be silly of me, but I've not managed to figure out why `anObject` in my example still has the property `MyType` introduces.

To clarify, I'm using generics instead of directly extending `MyClass` in order to be able to reuse the `MyType` contract along the code.

Comment: There's no such thing as casting in typescript. `<MyClass>` is a type assertion and it doesn't affect objects at runtime. All the types are erased at compile time https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions

Comment: You confuse runtime type with declared type. The `anObject` variable holds the same actual object as `res`, so no surprise the log shows it. Your cast does not make sense - you mislead typescript about the type of `anObject`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, [@Aleksey L.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113002/aleksey-l) and [@Tomasz Gawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1010868/tomasz-gawel). I've kept `MyType` the same and opted for adding the following to `MyClass`:

```
static fromObject<T extends MyClass>(o: T) {
    return new MyClass(o.prop1, o.prop2);
}
```

I know it uses static methods and all, but this is the cleanest solution I could come up with. Having this, I can call `let anObject: MyClass = MyClass.fromObject(res);`, solving both of the problems with my original approach.